# Computing on the Language in R

Tags: r

If I want to print the symbol denoting an object in R I can use quote():

```
> X <- list()
> print(quote(X))
X
>
```

However, if I have the function

```
h <- function(Y){
     quote(Y)
}
```

then

```
> h(X)
Y
>
```

Is it possible in R to write a function such that

```
> h(X)
X
```

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
> f = function(x) print(deparse(substitute(x)))
> f(asd)
[1] "asd"
>
```

Why? As you've found out `quote()` tells R to not evaluate a code block (which it does with `Y`). `substitute()` behaves differently; there's a good example at `?substitute`.

Answer (score 6):

```
h <- function(x) match.call()[['x']]

h(X)
X
```

Answer (score 0):

`substitute` also works without the extra calls:

```
h <- function(x) substitute(x)
h(X)
X
```